# Make element required when attribute is set to some value using XSD (1.1)

Tags: xsd, xsd-1.1

I have a following schema (1.1). I would like to have schema that will check that a sequence of parameters has mendatory parameter of type '1' and optional parameter of type '2'. I did it using alternatives because different types have different list of attributes.

How write an assertion to check that parameter of type 1 is mendatory?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
   <xs:element name="rule">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="conditions" maxOccurs="unbounded">
               <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                     <xs:element name="condition" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
                        <xs:complexType>
                           <xs:sequence>
                              <xs:element name="parameter" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
                                 <xs:alternative test="@type = '1'" type="typeOne"/>
                                 <xs:alternative test="@type = '2'" type="typeTwo" />
                              </xs:element>
                           </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                     </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:complexType name="typeOne">
      <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="typeTwo">
      <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I did it using alternatives because different types have different list of attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It would be like this:

```
<xs:element name="condition" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="parameter" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
                <xs:alternative test="@type = '1'" type="typeOne"/>
                <xs:alternative test="@type = '2'" type="typeTwo" />
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert id="type-1-mandatory" test="parameter[@type eq '1']"></xs:assert>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```